# dynamically changing href address based on the response from the server

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

i am currently trying to create pagination feature. I am using bootstrap for css and jQuery.

There are total of 8 divs that contains a tags.

in my html file, i wrote

```
<div id="articleArea" class="row">
 <div class="col-md-4 postTitle">
   <a href="#">post title</a>
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-4 postTitle">
   <a href="#">post title</a>
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-4 postTitle">
   <a href="#">post title</a>
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-4 postTitle">
   <a href="#">post title</a>
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-4 postTitle">
   <a href="#">post title</a>
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-4 postTitle">
   <a href="#">post title</a>
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-4 postTitle">
   <a href="#">post title</a>
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-4 postTitle">
   <a href="#">post title</a>
 </div>
</div>
```

what I want to do is replacing each href in a tags, based on the response from my ajax call. I will just post success part of .ajax since other parts are completely functional and irrelevant to my question. my ajax call is returned in json format and var result is an array that contains 8 different hrefs that need to be assigned to each a tags in postTitle divs.

```
success: function(data){
var result = data["result"];
 for(i=0; i < result.length; i++{
     postTitle = result[i];
     $(".postTitle.a").html(postTitle);
 }
},
```

If i execute this code, a href are shown briefly but it disappears within a second. How can I fix this? and if there is better way to implement this feature, please do comment! Would love to be hear any feedbacks.

Comment: what does your response data contains? only href or full ancher tag html in it?

Comment: `$(".postTitle.a").attr("href",postTitle)`

Comment: @MayankPandey just the href

Comment: unfortunately this will set href for a range of elements simultaneously and to one value

Comment: @VaibhavBhanushali just tried it, it is same as .html(postTitle), they vanish in less than a second

Comment: @PeterChung. Look at my answer. Let me know if that works

Comment: that's because you select all post titles on each iteration and by the time you get to `i==3` you've made changes to each of 8 tags that match, and at least three times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run iteration over a tags instead of running iteration over results

```
$(".postTitle a").each(function(i) {
  postTitle = result[i];
  $(this).attr("href",postTitle);
});
```

This would run over each href tag and replace the values accordingly

EDIT:  it should be `.postTitle a`

Comment: thank you so much! i'll accept your answer in 5 mins b/c stackoverflow is not letting me yet :)

Comment: hey if the result array had a length of 5 instead of 8, how would i leave the empty ones as empty? so only 5/8 divs would be filled with postTitle and rest would be %nbsp

Comment: 'if (i == result.length) break;' 
Add this at top of each funtion (under it). 
This will break the function and rest as will be uneffected

Answer (score 1):

Your selector would select all of the elements

```
$(".postTitle.a")
```

You should select each tag and set its href, in addition it is missing a space:

```
$(".postTitle a").each(function(index, value){
   $(value).attr('href', result[index]);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#pdf').change(function() {
      var newurl = $('#pdf').val();
      $('a.target').attr('href', newurl);
    });
});
```